# Unity top panel changed after resetting unity

Tags: unity, 14.04, panel

My Unity top panel has been changed to this after I did a reset to unity.

I installed unity tweak tool and then this command :

> unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity

and the top panel changed the way it looked before :
[image]
How can I revert back to the original top panel ?
[image]
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can adjust that by installing unity tweak tool as

**sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool**

then under unity , click on panel , there you can adjust transparacy level as your perference and even if tranparent panel doesnt occur then turn off background blur under search option that will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try reseting it again. If that did not help download ubuntu-tweak or My Unity and reset everything to default. I know this is not a complete answer but if I have 10 reputation I can post some screenshots. By The Way, you can download my unity by typeing

> sudo apt-get install myunity

Then under the panel tab change the transparency to 0

### If you use ccsm

First to install ccsm via terminal type

> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

launch ccsm and follow the instructions

[image]

under the desktop tab, select the ubuntu unity plugin:

[image]

and click the button I've highlighted:

[image]

and if you want to reset the icon theme too then I suggest you download the ubuntu tweak app. to download type

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

and now, under the tweaks tab:

[image]

Go to themes:

[image]

and reset everything:

[image]

Comment: where is the package myunity located ?

Comment: If you are using ubuntu 12.04 or above, you can download it via the software center or using the above command

Comment: also if you cannot find the myunity package, search in the software center 'compizconfig-settings-manager' and download it. If you choose to use ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) then please tell me and I'll tell you how to do it via ccsm.

Comment: I've added screenshots on how to reset icons and the top panel

Comment: I've added the answer that solves the issue. btw thanks for the detailed workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something changed the icon-pack in my unity.

Just went to Unity-Tweak Tool --> Icons --> Select "Ubuntu-mono dark"

That solves the issue :)